# Database Design for Car Dealership

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm looking into building an application for a car dealership. The biggest challenge I see is building the database to capture the necessary information about vehicles (year, make, model -- fairly easy, but I know the details go way beyond that). The information will probably be used to showcase the dealership's inventory on their website (so, users are probably going to want to be able to search based on various parameters, etc.).

Any suggestions on what I can do for version 1 of this database? Any samples out there that I can use? Thanks.

Comment: This information should be gathered when speaking to the customer when creating your requirements documentation, not guessed at a later date. Your customer will know what the 'various parameters' are for searching with, and what the users 'probably' want to search for should also be defined by speaking with your customer and capturing requirements before you even think about opening Enterprise Manager.

Comment: This is far too open ended for Stack Overflow - sorry :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look at http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/ , there is a bunch of db models which you can compare.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend creating your database on paper first. While it is in diagram form, it can be refactored and redesigned without any time loss, and can be used to explain the inner workings of your database in a much more clearer way - if not to others, to yourself.

The best way in doing this is with a standardised procedure called UML. Check out http://sourcemaking.com/uml/introduction as it has a lot of information on getting started with UML and software development best practices.